# Замена update на insert sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Есть таблица `send`, в которой есть поля `id` и `name`. `id` обычное поле, не primarykey. В таблице будут всего две записи с `id` = 1 и `id` = 2. Данные записи могут быть удалены. Есть 2 sql запроса:

```
 "UPDATE send SET name = '...' WHERE id = '1'"
```

и

```
 "UPDATE send SET name = '...' WHERE id = '2'"
```

Как переписать данные запросы так, чтобы, если записи с таким `id` нет (то есть update не произошел), тогда срабатывала команда

```
 "INSERT INTO send (id, name) VALUES('1', '...')"
```

и

```
 "INSERT INTO send (id, name) VALUES('2', '...')"
```

соответственно для второго запроса.

Хотелось это как-нибудь сделать одним запросом. В MS SQL все было просто: написал хранимку, сделал UPDATE получил @@ROWCOUNT, и, соответственно, на основании его сделал INSERT, а как быть в SQLite вообще не пойму.

Comment: в 2 запроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277373/sqlite-upsert-update-or-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте уникальный индекс по полю ID.
2. Используйте запрос

   ```
   REPLACE INTO send (id, name) VALUES('1', '...')
   ```

Если записи с указанным ID нет - она вставится, если есть - заменится.